# Node.js/MongoDB perform multi-keyword search

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to implement a basic keyword search where the user can enter 1-3 keywords in separate form input fields and receive an output of matching documents.

My model has 3 fields for keywords as shown below:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var animalSchema = new Schema (
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
        type: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
        location: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
        keyword_1: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
        keyword_2: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
        keyword_3: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 }
    }
);
```

Ideally the user shouldn't have to type the keywords in the order that they're saved in the database collection to get a match. For example, a user input of: **brown, cat** in this order should return a match for an animal document with the fields: **keyword_1: grumpy, keyword_2: cat, keyword_3: brown**.

Thanks

Comment: [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) should be able to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your reply, went for a different approach and used JavaScript regex.